How to show a SFSafariViewController without the option to open it in a browser
I am using a SFSafariViewController for a sign-in page. I want to disable the option to open the webpage in an external browser. Is there a simple way to hide the browser icon in the bottom right corner?
if let url = URL(string: "[URL]") {
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
    vc.dismissButtonStyle = .cancel
    present(vc, animated: true)
}

I couldn't find any easy solution. Do I need to recreate the entire view?
The icon I want to hide:


I wasn't aware of ASWebAuthenticationSession, but it suits my needs better and offers the exact options I need.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
